# mysql forein key error

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys

The below result of SHOW ENGINE INNODB STATUS shows an offending ADD FOREIGN KEY query but I have no idea why it fails. The references are all ok, mysql check does not give any error either.

At the bottom I also added the results of SHOW CREATE TABLE for both tables.

What is the reason for this error?

```
LATEST FOREIGN KEY ERROR
------------------------
130628 18:28:22 Transaction:
TRANSACTION 21F28, ACTIVE 0 sec inserting
mysql tables in use 2, locked 2
18 lock struct(s), heap size 3112, 1304 row lock(s), undo log entries 1174
MySQL thread id 12864, OS thread handle 0x7f8171f8d700, query id 107567 localhost root copy to tmp table
ALTER TABLE `entry` ADD FOREIGN KEY (`journal`) REFERENCES  `aqqounts`.`journal`(`id`) ON DELETE RESTRICT ON UPDATE RESTRICT
Foreign key constraint fails for table `aqqounts`.`#sql-389_3240`:
,
  CONSTRAINT `?sql?389_3240_ibfk_1` FOREIGN KEY (`journal`) REFERENCES `journal` (`id`)
Trying to add in child table, in index `journal` tuple:
DATA TUPLE: 2 fields;
 0: len 4; hex 00000199; asc     ;;
 1: len 2; hex 0cfe; asc   ;;

But in parent table `aqqounts`.`journal`, in index `PRIMARY`,
the closest match we can find is record:
PHYSICAL RECORD: n_fields 8; compact format; info bits 0
 0: len 4; hex 0000019a; asc     ;;
 1: len 6; hex 000000021ec9; asc       ;;
 2: len 7; hex 6500000e3b2f19; asc e   ;/ ;;
 3: len 4; hex 00000003; asc     ;;
 4: len 4; hex 51cda573; asc Q  s;;
 5: len 4; hex 51cdac00; asc Q   ;;
 6: len 3; hex 8fb39e; asc    ;;
 7: len 4; hex 00000000; asc     ;;


| entry | CREATE TABLE `entry` (
  `id` smallint(5) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `journal` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `ledger` int(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT '2900',
  `amount` decimal(12,2) NOT NULL,
  `vat` int(2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `relation` varchar(30) NOT NULL,
  `description` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `journal` (`journal`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5301 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 |


| journal | CREATE TABLE `journal` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00' COMMENT 'trigger is needed',
  `updated` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `date` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `account` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=1042 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci |
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe because you already have an invalid data stored in table `entry` under `journal` column e.g. if you have a record in `entry` where `journal` = 1 but you don't have that in `journal`.

Also you should try to name your foreign keys identically e.g. `journal`.`journalId` and `entry`.`journalId`

Comment: references are all correct. And I do not think the names should be the same, I cannot find anything in the manual about that.

Comment: of course. it is a suggestion.

and as I said - search inside table `entry` to see if all `journal` fields values exist as a records in `journal` table.

Comment: Yes, that was the problem. I thought I had covered that by looking for null values for the id field in the journal table, but with a inner join, instead of a left join. Then I read a lot about bugs in mysql and I got confused.

Comment: If you edit your answer removing the second paragraph, I will accept it.